# 400 Bad request socket

Tags: python, sockets, networking, websocket, python-requests

I am learning Network programming with Coursera and currently trying to do a basic exercise with socket. This is my code:

```
import socket

mysock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
mysock.connect(('data.pr4e.org', 80))
cmd = 'GET https://data.pr4e.org/romeo.txt HTTP/1.1\r\n\r\n'.encode()
mysock.send(cmd)

while True:
    data=mysock.recv(512)
    if (len(data)<1):
        break
    print(data.decode())
mysock.close()
```

But every time I do it, it shows this:

```
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Date: Wed, 20 Apr 2022 18:54:53 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu)
Content-Length: 308
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1

<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>400 Bad Request</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Bad Request</h1>
<p>Your browser sent a request that this server could not understand.<br />
</p>
<hr>
<address>Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu) Server at do1.dr-chuck.com Port 80</address>
</body></html>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTTP 1.1 requires that you at least send a Host header along with your request.

Something like this may work:

```
# ...
cmd = 'GET /romeo.txt HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: data.pr4e.org\r\n\r\n'.encode()
mysock.send(cmd)
# ...
```

Comment: And also putting the full URL in the GET request is wrong.

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk While it is uncommon to send the full URL in the request line, it is entirely valid. See https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc2616#section-5.2 and https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc2616#section-19.6.1.1

Comment: @HolgerJust: Kind of. The RFC says that servers must accept this but clients will only do this for proxy requests. The reality is that a significant portion of servers (most?) does not accept this.

Comment: @HolgerJust: The OP is attempting a HTTPS URL. Your code provides a plain HTTP request only, i.e. you've showed how to resolve one of the problems in the OPs code but not the other.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich: (1) The RFC 2616 requires that servers support it. While not all do (hence my comment that it is uncommon to include the hostname in the request line), at least Apache httpd, lighttpd support this just fine, even with an empty Host header. nginx appears to (generally) require a filled Host header but uses the host value from the full request URI for (if given) when selecting the virtual hsot. (2) OP has send the `https` scheme in their request URI but has not made any attempt to actually open a TLS tunnel. Thus, this was likely a typo.